# How to validate start and end date in angular template driven approach?

Tags: angular, date, angular-validation

I have 2 dates inputs in my form as show below:

```
<label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
    <input type="date" name="startDate" placeholder="Start Date" class="form-control" ngModel required #startDate="ngModel">
    <span *ngIf="!startDate.valid && startDate.touched" class="error-msg">
     <span *ngIf="startDate.errors.required">Start Date is required</span>
     </span>
     <br/>
 <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
 <input type="date" name="endDate" placeholder="End Date" class="form-control" ngModel required #endDate="ngModel" >
    <span *ngIf="!endDate.valid && endDate.touched" class="error-msg">
    <span *ngIf="endDate.errors.required">End Date is required</span>
    </span>
```

And i want to allow the user to select dates only form the start date. I am tried using the `min` attribute but not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `min` attribute

```
 <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
 <input type="date" name="endDate" placeholder="End Date" class="form-control" ngModel required #endDate="ngModel" min="{{your_form_name.value.startDate}}">
```